# MVC: Best way for a hyperlink to post back to an ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a Html.BeginForm but I need a hyperlink to trigger a postback to a ActionResult (similar functionality to a LinkButton).  I don't think that I can use an ActionLink because i'm not routing to a view with the same name as the ActionResult (or have I misunderstood :S).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You mean that you want to change the target for your form based on which button they click?  Or will the form *always* post to the other target?

Comment: Your link doesn't route to a view, your controllers do that. You point your ActionLink at `/{controller}/MyAction` and the controller does the work of deciding which view to render. Can you be more specific about the routes and controller names you're using?

Comment: Basically I just need a hyperlink to behave the same as a submit button.  So...when the hyperlink is clicked, the form will post to an actionresult passing in a number of parameters.  The actionresult will then return a return a partial view.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so I created this: @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "PostExample", null, new { id = "exampleCssId" }).  But i wanted to link it to an ActionResult in my Home controller and the ActionResult method to route to a different partial view.  At the moment, i'm getting a 404 error, because it cannot find a view called 'PostExample'.

Comment: If you're posting to an action in another controller, you'll need to use a different overload of `Html.ActionLink`, namely `ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeArguments, object htmlAttributes)` (I think they're in that order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two options (though the first isn't as flexible and can get messy)

1) style your submit button like a hyperlink (easy, but you'll probably end up using `Html.BeginAjax` or something like that)

2) Style a div, ActionLink, or some other element and serialize the form data on posting back using jQuery

If you can better describe the data being returned, we can better customize the `dataType` and `success` parameters below.

```
$(function () {
    $('#myButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/MyController/MySuperAction',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#formId').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (xhr_data) {
                // in this particular example, you'll
                // parse your JSON returned.
            }
        });
    });
});
```

### Edit

So, you're controller could look like

```
public ActionResult MySuperAction(FormCollection form) {
    // I don't recommend using FormCollection
    // You should stick to the view model pattern

    // process your form
    return Json(new { MyValue = "Textbox value" });
}
```

And you'd need to modify the `success` function above to something like

```
success: function(xhr_data) {
    $('#MyTextBoxID').val(xhr_data.MyValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  The only data that would have to be returned is simply a textbox value.

Comment: Isn't there a shorter and cleaner way perhaps `Ajax.ActionLink` or some other thingy?